# what is the maximum number of photo one instagram supports

Tags: facebook, architecture, filesystems, startup, distributed-system

The question is just the subject.
I am thinking of creating an app that pushes all the images from my phone to an Instagram account, which will keep the pictures in a private state.
So essentially that will replace the subscription alternative of google photos.
PS: It is fine to use Instagram or facebook,
The reason being the meta software will also help me face detect users of my friends, and create a ai generated commentary of my pictures that will help me organize and sort picture.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a strict limit for instagram on the 'maximum' number of images you can upload to the platform.

However there appears to be a maximum of 100 uploads limit per user in a 24 hours period, but bare in mind that if whatever you are trying to do is done in bulk and frequently over time and exceeds the limit may make you look like a bot, which may resulting your account gets banned immediately.